# How to generate list object into multiple list base on a object property?

Tags: java, android

This is my object

```
public static class Phone{
    public String model;
    public String imei;
    public String date_active;

}
```

This is my list object example

```
Phone a = new Phone ("Qs17", "1122", "20/10/2014");
Phone b = new Phone ("Qs18", "4345", "20/10/2014");
Phone c = new Phone ("Qs19", "3451", "21/10/2014");
Phone d = new Phone ("Qs20", "6756", "22/10/2014");
Phone e = new Phone ("Qs17", "1257", "22/10/2014");
Phone f = new Phone ("Qs17", "9077", "22/10/2014");

list.add(a);
list.add(b);
list.add(c);
list.add(d);
list.add(e);
list.add(f);
```

I want split my list to some multiple list which has the same date.
Example:

```
list1 = [{"QS17","1122","20/10/2014"}, {"QS18","4345","20/10/2014"}]
list2 = [{"QS19","3451","21/10/2014"}]
list3 = [{"QS20","6756","22/10/2014"}, {"QS17","1257","22/10/2014"}, {"QS17","9077","22/10/2014"}]
```

I seach some way on web, and found this

```
static <T> List<List<T>> chopped(List<T> list, final int L) {
List<List<T>> parts = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
final int N = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < N; i += L) {
    parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(
        list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + L)))
    );
}
return parts;
```

}

But seem it depend on specific number to sublist, not base on a property of object.

I also search to find a another way, and found this

```
Map<YourSplitterProperty, List<YourItem>> map = new HashMap<YourSplitterProperty, List<YourItem>();
for (YourItem item : yourItems) {
   List<YourItem> list = map.get(item.getSplitterProperty());
  if (list == null) {
    list = new ArrayList<YourItem>();
    map.put(item.getSplitterProperty(), list);
  }
  list.add(item);
}
```

But this way only return a list, I need to return multiple list which have the same property on root list.

May anybody help me ?

Comment: Nuong, quite unclear your question, can you please clarify it more.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza, I want split my list into multiple list which have the same date_active

Comment: @pratt how to do a kind of *group by* from a `List<Phone>` by a specific property of `Phone` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method will split the `List<T>` in smaller lists of the same size. The second method will split the list into smaller lists based on the value of a field stored in the elements of the list. From the result shown in your method, you're looking for the second method but with some changes:

- Return the `List<T>` as `List<List<T>>` rather than `Map<Key, List<T>`.
- The returned `List<List<T>>` should also be sorted.

You can achieve this by using `TreeMap` as `Map` implementation. This would be the modifications you're looking for:

```
public static List<List<Phone>> splitByDateActive(List<Phone> phoneList) {
    Map<String, List<Phone>> map =
        new TreeMap<String, List<Phone>();
    for (Phone phone : phoneList) {
        List<Phone> list = map.get(phone.getDate_active());
        if (list == null) {
            list = new ArrayList<Phone>();
            map.put(phone.getDate_active(), list);
        }
        list.add(phone);
    }
    List<List<Phone>> phoneListSplitted = new ArrayList<List<Phone>>();
    for (List<Phone> phoneListVar : map.values()) {
        phoneListSplitted.addAll(phoneListVar);
    }
    return phoneListSplitted;
}
```

Comment: Dear @Luiggi, Have error at method getValues() and method .addAll(phoneListVar)

Comment: it work excelent, just need replace addAll by add. Your answer is solution. Many thanks.